# Как выбрать строки по условию, только чтобы те, которые не подходят условию не выводились?

Tags: sql

Как выбрать строки по условию, только чтобы те, которые не подходят условию не выводились?

Я пишу *case*, и строки, которые не подходят условию, выводятся как NULL. Вот код:

```
select  
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK.FIO_OTV END FACT_KOL_DAYS , 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN SLP.NSLP END Profession, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN POD.NAIM_PS  END PODRAZD, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.D1_KDK6 END BEGIN_DATE, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.D2_KDK6 END END_DATE,
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.KOL_DAYF END FACT_KOL_DAYS, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN(SELECT SUM(KPREZ.KOL_DAYP) FROM KPREZ WHERE
YEAR(KPREZ.DATEPLWK) = '2015' AND KPREZ.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK )END DAYS_PO_PLANY 
from   pod, KDK
left join KDK6 on KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
left join SLP ON SLP.KSLP = KDK.KSLP
left join KDK5 ON KDK5.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
LEFT JOIN KPREZ ON KPREZ.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
where
POD.CEH = KDK5.CEH
AND
KDK5.D_KDK5 IN (SELECT MAX (KDK5.D_KDK5) FROM KDK5 WHERE KDK5.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK)
GROUP BY KDK.FIO_OTV, SLP.NSLP,  KDK6.D1_KDK6, KDK6.D2_KDK6 ,  KDK6.N_KDK, KDK.N_KDK, pod.NAIM_PS, KDK6.KOL_DAYF
ORDER BY KDK.FIO_OTV
```

вот что выводится (а мне нужно чтоб строка, где все поля null, не выводилась):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где условие WHERE?

Answer (score 1):

```
use IHF;
select  
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK.FIO_OTV END FACT_KOL_DAYS , 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN SLP.NSLP END Profession, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN POD.NAIM_PS  END PODRAZD, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.D1_KDK6 END BEGIN_DATE, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.D2_KDK6 END END_DATE,
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN KDK6.KOL_DAYF END FACT_KOL_DAYS, 
CASE WHEN ((YEAR (KDK6.D2_KDK6) - YEAR(KDK6.D1_KDK6)<2) OR ((KDK6.D1_KDK6 IS NULL) AND (KDK6.D2_KDK6 IS NULL)))THEN(SELECT SUM(KPREZ.KOL_DAYP) FROM KPREZ WHERE
YEAR(KPREZ.DATEPLWK) = '2015' AND KPREZ.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK )END DAYS_PO_PLANY 
from   pod, KDK
inner join KDK6 on KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
left join SLP ON SLP.KSLP = KDK.KSLP
left join KDK5 ON KDK5.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
LEFT JOIN KPREZ ON KPREZ.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK
where
POD.CEH = KDK5.CEH
AND
KDK5.D_KDK5 IN (SELECT MAX (KDK5.D_KDK5) FROM KDK5 WHERE KDK5.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK)
GROUP BY KDK.FIO_OTV, SLP.NSLP,  KDK6.D1_KDK6, KDK6.D2_KDK6 ,  KDK6.N_KDK, KDK.N_KDK, pod.NAIM_PS, KDK6.KOL_DAYF
ORDER BY KDK.FIO_OTV
```

Answer (score 0):

В Where проверяете KDK5 - а в запросе выводите KDK6.
Как результат - есть записи, подходящие под выборку (`POD.CEH = KDK5.CEH`), но для них не нашлось подходящих записей из KDK6 (`KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK`).
Или делайте Inner join, или ограничивайте выборку по KDK6.

Comment: Условие POD.CEH = KDK5.CEH нужно по-любому, inner join не помог избавится от null-строк =(

Comment: Я понимаю, что оно нужно. Но inner join вместо left join на kdk6 должен был отфильтровать null-строки. Покажите запрос, в котором заменили left на inner

Comment: inner join KDK6 on KDK6.N_KDK = KDK.N_KDK (единственная измененная строка, а все остальное - то же самое). И не работает =(